# ShowMessage in Delphi XE5 Shortended

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe5

`ShowMessage()` in Delphi XE5 shortens text.

Is this new to me, or it is due to the encoded characters when encoding a url? I need to see the entire thing.

I use the following function to encode my url:

```
function TConnector.EncodeUrl(aDecodedUrl: String): String;
begin
  result:= tIdUri.URLEncode(aDecodedUrl);
end;
```

I then call in here:

```
zEncodedUrl := Connector.EncodeUrl('http://' + Connector.Host + 'Node:' + edtPath.Text + '.GetObjectListDataAsJSON');
```

**EDIT:** And I get this when passed to ShowMessage:

[image: screenshot]

I should note that when debugging and placing my mouse over the `zEncodedUrl` variable, it shows the full thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the native behaviour of the Vista task dialog, at least as called by Delphi. And the Vista task dialog is what gets called when you call `ShowMessage` on Windows. It will not split lines that are too long. If your text included a space, it would be split.

A simple workaround would be to call good old `MessageBox`.

```
MessageBox(Application.MainForm.Handle, PChar(Message), PChar(Caption), MB_OK);
```

You may want to fine-tune the choice of owner `HWND` to pass, but you get the idea.

Comment: YES! I was just using that :) But thanks for the great expanation of what is going on. ANy idea if there is an option to switch back to the showmessage window we all like? :)

Comment: Well, you can set `UseLatestCommonDialogs` to `False`, but that will screw up your file dialogs too. And the resulting message box is pretty lame. It won't break the lines at all. Honestly, `MessageBox` is the best choice here.